# Number Formatting Dynamic columns in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, dynamic-columns

I've been picking this one up and putting it down for a few months now and have spent several hours on trying to figure out how to set up the right expression. I have a dataset that is dynamic based on the parameters chosen. for example AHT(Average handle time), Adherence and %of time in personal break.

So what I need it to do is if its AHT I need it to find the max value and divide that by the number of entries then display that in a HH:MM:SS format. If it's adherence I need it to do the same thing but display in Percentage format and same for personal breaks.

This is the expression I tried to build I've tried a few instances of it and not getting what I want as I usually just get #error.

```
=AVG(Fields!ACTUALVALUE.Value(IIF(Fields!KPINAME.Value = "AHT",
    FORMAT(dateadd("s", Fields!KPINAME.Value, "00:00:00"), "hh:mm:ss"))
```

I know this is way too far off to work but for the life of me can not figure out how to do this any hints or points in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Picture of the table and set up]

Below is a picture of how it spits out when I just do Max or AVG. AHT is showing in Seconds and Break and Total personal are just showing up as number.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the IIF, the syntax is

```
=IIF(<CONDITION (i.e. x=1)>, < This if true>, < else this>)
```

Since the table is grouping by the KPI Name, the KPI Name should be outside of the aggregate then the different formats can be used for each KPI:

```
=IIF(Fields!KPINAME.Value = "AHT", 
        FORMAT(DATEADD("s", AVG(Fields!ACTUALVALUE.Value)), "00:00:00"),
        FORMAT(DATEADD("s", AVG(Fields!ACTUALVALUE.Value)), "0.0%")
    )
```

Comment: Hey Hannover,  Thank you for you're response. I'm getting the following error.
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The Value expression for the textrun ‘ACTUALVALUE.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30516] Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'DateAdd' accepts this number of arguments.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2010Impl.CreateReportEditSession(String Report, String Parent, Byte[] Definition, String& EditSessionID, Warning[]& Warnings)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010....